# CalendarProvider, how to get meeting's owner name?

Tags: android, android-calendar

I need to get the meeting's owner name from the CalendarProvider.
I've found these two rows:

```
CalendarContract.Events.ORGANIZER,
CalendarContract.Events.OWNER_ACCOUNT
```

But they return only creator's email.

How can I fetch the creator's name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you quired all needed events, when you are in Cursor loop, for every event you can get a name by this method:

```
private String getOrganizerNameFromAttendees(int eventId, String organizerMail) {
    Logger.e(TAG, "getOrganizerNameFromAttendees");
    final String[] args = new String[]{String.valueOf(eventId), organizerMail};
    final Cursor cursor = mApplicationContext.getContentResolver().query(CalendarContract.Attendees.CONTENT_URI, ATTENDEE_PROJECTION, ATTENDEE_SELECTION, args, null);

    String name = null;
    try {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String nameFromAttendees = cursor.getString(ATTENDEE_PROJECTION_NAME_INDEX);
            String mailFromAttendees = cursor.getString(ATTENDEE_PROJECTION_MAIL_INDEX);
            name = TextUtils.isEmpty(nameFromAttendees) ? mailFromAttendees : nameFromAttendees;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.e(TAG, "getOrganizerNameFromAttendees, exception = " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for getting Events details.
For more details you can check google android calendar docs
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider

```
  // add below permission in your app manifest file and also ask these two permission at run time
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>

   // add below method in your activity
   public void getOrganizerName() {
    Cursor cur = null;
    ContentResolver cr =getContentResolver();
    Uri uri=CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] eventmProjection =
            {CalendarContract.Calendars._ID,
                    CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART,
                    CalendarContract.Events.DTEND,
                    CalendarContract.Events.TITLE,
                    CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION,
                    CalendarContract.Events.ORGANIZER,
                    CalendarContract.Events._ID,
                    CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION,
                    CalendarContract.Events.DURATION,
                    CalendarContract.Events.SYNC_DATA1,
                    CalendarContract.Events.DIRTY,
                    CalendarContract.Events.UID_2445,
                    CalendarContract.Events.DELETED,
                    CalendarContract.Events.LAST_DATE,
                    CalendarContract.Events.SYNC_DATA2,
                    CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY,
                    CalendarContract.Events.RRULE,
                    CalendarContract.Events.STATUS,
                    CalendarContract.Events.RDATE
            };

    String selection = "(" + CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME + " = ? AND deleted != 1 AND " + CalendarContract.Events.ORGANIZER + " != ?)";
  // pass here google calendar sync account detials
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"abc@gmail.com","abc@gmail.com"};

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR},12);
    }
    cur = cr.query(uri, eventmProjection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
    if(cur.getCount()>0){
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String eventTitle = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE));
            String eventId = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events._ID));
            String startDate = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART));
            String endDate = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND));
            String org_name=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events.ORGANIZER));
            Log.d("Events", "->" + eventTitle + "->" + eventId + "->" + startDate + "->" + endDate+ "->"+org_name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have such code, Events table doesn't contain the organizer's name. It has only his email. That's the problem.

Comment: i have tested above code its working and also getting organizer name

Comment: In this case, you are fetching your sync account name. But this code won't work if you are not a creator.